# Can I display file structure in Html 4 with Accordian

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

..or something else.

I would like to make file structure fully collapsible within html 4.
I've already used JQuery and Accordian to  group sections by their 1st letter, but it doesn't seem accordian lends itself to grouping more than one level down.

In screenshot you can see Ive used Accordian for the Discogs Summary section.
My problem is with the Song Changes section, I would like it obe represented as a collapsible/expandable folder structure.

[image: Current version of html report]

Comment: To me accordion doesn't seem like the right tool, try jstree, perfect for doing a file/folder type structure http://www.jstree.com/

Comment: And your question is....?

Comment: My question is 'How do i display a collapsible file structure in html'

Comment: thx ojay , jstree looks like it should be able to do what i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get something working with jstree, once Id cut down their example to something more manageable.

[image]

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.jstree.com/v.1.0pre/jquery.jstree.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" class="source below">
$(function () {
    $("#songchanges")
        .jstree({
            "plugins" : ["themes","html_data","ui","crrm","hotkeys"],
            "core" : { "initially_open" : [ "phtml_1" ] }
        })
        .bind("loaded.jstree", function (event, data) {
        });
    $("#songchanges").bind("open_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
        data.inst.select_node("#phtml_2", true);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="songchanges">
    <ul>
        <li id="phtml_1">
            <a href="#">C:\Music</a>
            <ul>
                <li id="phtml_2">
                    <a href="#">B</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="phtml_3">
                            <a href="#">Blur</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li id="phtml_4">
                                        <a href="FixSongsReport_2.html">Leisure</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li id="phtml_5">
                                        <a href="FixSongsReport_1.html">ParkLife</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>       
                </li>   
                <li id="phtml_6">
                    <a href="#">V</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="phtml_7">
                            <a href="#">Various Artists</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li id="phtml_8">
                                        <a href="FixSongsReport_1.html">World War II Songs</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li id="phtml_9">
                                        <a href="FixSongsReport_2.html">Moonlight Classics</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```